# Stopping a nuclear missile?

Tags: nuclear, nuclear-war

Would you be able to stop a nuclear missile by hitting it with a liquid nitrogen missile, As a means to prevent the nuclear radiation from spreading or falling to the ground from impact?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Ted! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "a liquid nitrogen missile".  Could you please clarify this?  It is possible to stop a nuclear missile by hitting it with another missile, the trick is to have precise enough targeting and the ability to counter any opposing dodges so your missile can get close enough to destroy the other missile.

Comment: If you hit it with a rock you can stop it... Problem is hitting it is hard...

Comment: Gryphon is right, you should provide more information on your situation.

Comment: That small edit is nowhere near enough to justify reopening.  Since a quick Google check suggests liquid nitrogen missiles are toys fueled by liquid nitrogen and not actual military missiles (correct me if I'm wrong), then you need to completely explain the nature and use of a liquid nitrogen missile.  then you need to explain which nuclear missile we're shooting at, where it's coming from, where it's going to, the weather at the time of impact at the zone of impact....  As-is, this isn't answerable.

Comment: I'm talking like is it possible to use liquid nitrogen to freeze a airborne nuclear missile to prevent the nuclear head from exploding upon impact or if it were to collide  in mid air could the liquid nitrogen be used to stop the nuclear radiation from causing damage upon descent from the sky?

Comment: You really need to study some basic physics.  For starters, nuclear weapons have quite complex mechanisms.  Break those, by e.g. hitting it real hard, and they don't explode.  If they don't explode, they don't do much damage.  And when they do explode, it's not the "radiation" that's the immediate problem, it's the near-instantaneous release of a lot of heat that vaporizes things nearby, causes shockwaves, &c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: **NO**

Long answer: a liquid nitrogen missile is nothing more than a mass of liquid contained in a missile, impacting the incoming nuclear missile. While kinetic weapons can be used to destroy the target, it is preferable to use dense materials, in order to deliver larger amount of kinetic energy. Using liquid nitrogen for this is like using a sponge baseball bat to hit someone intruding your house.

If the goal of using liquid nitrogen is to use the cooling consequent to the evaporation of the nitrogen as a mean to embrittle the nuclear missile, it's a vane hope: evaporation of nitrogen and cooling of the mass of the missile takes time, while the impact will last, at most, few tenths of seconds.

The only effect you would achieve would be a nice puff of condensing humidity once the liquid nitrogen gets sprinkled around by the impact and start evaporating, cooling the atmosphere around it.

Comment: The amount of damage required to disable a nuclear warhead is amazingly small. Any sort of damage to the nose cone will cause the warhead to disintegrate due to aerodynamic stress long before it gets to detonation distance. Even a blob of LN2 (without tanks or missile structure) meeting an incoming ICBM (closing speed 8 to 16 km/sec) will do enough damage to make survival to detonation extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes

But you don't need to go to the trouble of filling your missile with Liquid nitrogen. Just the fact that you hit it with another missile is typically going to be enough to prevent the missile from exploding with a nuclear reaction.